# jquery - disable all select boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot (~100+) select boxes and each with it's own unique select id. I now want to disable all select boxes in case a user does not have the adequate access levels, but cannot seem to find a way to globally address all select boxes.

Below my attempt to do this via JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('load', function () {
        this.attr('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

> Just do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this when the body has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('load', function() 
    {
        $('select').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("select").attr("disabled", "true")
});
```

Unless you are doing some funky ajax loading, the ready() event should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
(function(){
   $("select").attr("disabled", true);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").prop("disabled", "true");
});

//you should use prop intead
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').prop('disabled', true);;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

disable all `<select>`

```
$('select').attr('disabled', true)
```

& disable only options of `<select>`

```
$('select').find('option').attr('disabled', true)
```